# Set ValidateAntiForgeryToken Attribute to work on a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I have a generic MVC controller with a POST action. This controller is used in a common project used by multiple applications. We are attempting to add CSRF protection in a staggered release process where we add CSRF protection via the Anti Forgery Token for each application one at a time.

If I add the validation attribute, `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` to this controller but only include the Anti Forgery Token hidden form element in the views of 1 of the applications this will cause havoc for the other applications. How can I apply this attribute based on a condition. Is this possible? Does this need to be done manually similar to the code below? Is there a better way?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GenericSection(string nextController, string nextAction, FormCollection form)
    {
        // Validate anti-forgery token if applicable
        if (SessionHandler.CurrentSection.IncludeAntiForgeryToken)
        {
            try
            {
                AntiForgery.Validate();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log error and throw exception
            }
        }

        // If successful continue on and do logic
    }
```

Comment: What you can do is, skip the validation of antiforgery token based on some configuration. Did you get the expected behavior with the code you shared?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, the code above produces the correct result however, I was hoping that there was a better approach where it would still be possible to use an annotation thus removing the bulk from the controller method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you decorate the controller action method with `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute, you can not escape by not putting the hidden field in the view.

You need to figure out a way where, you have the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute, have the hidden field for the token in the view but validate the token only when needed.

For the below solution, I assume that the multiple applications you are talking about has `web.config` file.

What you need to do is, introduce a new configuration in `appSettings`, such as `IsAntiForgeryTokenValidationEnabled` or some better shorter name.

Create a new attribute class as following and check the configuration value. If the configuration value is `true` go ahead and validate the token else just skip it.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CheckAntiForgeryTokenValidation : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IIdentityConfigManager _configManager = CastleClassFactory.Instance.Resolve<IIdentityConfigManager>();
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var configValue = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsAntiForgeryTokenValidationEnabled"];
        //Do not validate the token if the config value is not provided or it's value is not "true".
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(configValue) || configValue != "true")
        {
            return;
        }
        // Validate the token if the configuration value is "true".
        else
        {
            new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute().OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

`OnAuthorization` method of above class will be executed before the action method where this attribute is used and validate or not validate the token based on the configuration value.

Now you need to use this attribute on the controller action method as following example.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     [HttpPost]
     [CheckAntiForgeryTokenValidation]
     public ActionResult Save()
     {
         // Code of saving.
     }
}
```

After this all the applications which want to validate the AntiForgeryToken need to have the configuration `IsAntiForgeryTokenValidationEnabled` in their configuration file with value `true`. The token validation is not available by default, so if existing applications don't have the configurations, they still work without any issues.

I hope this would help you resolve your issue.

Comment: This works perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Much more elegant approach.